# PermissionError: [WinError 32] None:

Tags: python, error-handling

```
import send2trash

baconFile = open('bacon.txt', 'w')
baconFile.write('Bacon is nice')
baconFile.close()


send2trash.send2trash('bacon.txt')
```

I have the above code, and when I try to call `send2trash.send2trash()` it's giving me the following error:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-d3b747586237> in <module>
      6 
      7 
----> 8 send2trash.send2trash('bacon.txt')

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win.py in send2trash(path)
     84     result = SHFileOperationW(byref(fileop))
     85     if result:
---> 86         raise WindowsError(None, None, path, result)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] None: 'C:\\Users\\****\\bacon.txt'
```

I have checked a lot of answers here and all of them say to close the file with `close()` function, but i did this initially and it still has this error. I am using Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda.

What is the problem?

Comment: have you tried using a context manger `with open(...): .... ` which will close the file for you?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf no, how do I do it? And can this help me with my situation?

Comment: I just added an answer, so please let me know if that works. Otherwise, I think your file might be used by other process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers) to make sure the file is closed before calling `send2trash.send2trash('bacon.txt')`:

```py
import send2trash

with open('bacon.txt', 'w') as baconFile:
    baconFile.write('Bacon is nice')

send2trash.send2trash('bacon.txt')
```

Comment: no :(, it's not working. I get exactly the same error

Comment: @ThePoorJew, is your file used by another process? I mean is it open by another program?

Comment: to my knowledge, no, it's not open.

Comment: @ThePoorJew, can you make sure that the file exists with its content before you call `send2trash`?

Comment: ok so I'm working through a book ('Automate the boring stuff'), and it's possible that this file (previously used by the author and me) is open in my script for this book. I created a different name for the file and all is working.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @ThePoorJew, I'm very happy I was able to help you :).